# Include Graphics using fmtcount \padzeros to determine filename

Tags: graphics, fmtcount

I'm trying to include a lot of images to document and decided to use a counter to generate the filenames. A minimal (not working) example would look something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\newcounter{imgnr}

\begin{document}    
    % image names are img000.png, img001.png, ..., img999.png
    \setcounter{imgnr}{1}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{./images/img\padzeroes[3]\decimal{imgnr}.png}
    \setcounter{imgnr}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{./images/img\padzeroes[3]\decimal{imgnr}.png}
    \setcounter{imgnr}{10}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{./images/img\padzeroes[3]\decimal{imgnr}.png}
\end{document}
```

This example gives the error `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]`. Any idea on how to fix this? Or is this the wrong way to go?

In the real example, the counter is incremented and then a template with title, some text and tables and the image is included for each image. So thats the reason why im using a counter. I can nicely select the data for a given image.

Bonus: Display a box with `Image 'imgxxx.png' is missing` if a image is not found.

Comment: Just found out that `\decimal` might not be expandable: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/86la9mMQVXI/kgW0vrArcTUJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an expandable version of the padding. The following example redefines `\theimgnr` to expand to a number padded with zeros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcounter{imgnr}
\renewcommand{\theimgnr}{%
  \ifnum\value{imgnr}<10 0\fi
  \ifnum\value{imgnr}<100 0\fi
  \the\value{imgnr}%
}

\begin{document}
    % image names are img000.png, img001.png, ..., img999.png
    \setcounter{imgnr}{1}

\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{./images/img\theimgnr.png}
    \setcounter{imgnr}{2}

\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{./images/img\theimgnr.png}
    \setcounter{imgnr}{10}

\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{./images/img\theimgnr.png}
\end{document}
```

## Expandable macro `\padnum` for TeX numbers

The number range of TeX's numbers are limited, the largest number is 2<sup>31</sup>-1. Therefore macro `\padnum` uses this fact to make its implementation simple. The first argument is the number of digits, the second is a number between 0 and 2<sup>31</sup>-1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcounter{imgnr}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\padnum}[2]{%
  \ifnum#1>1 \ifnum#2<10 0\fi
  \ifnum#1>2 \ifnum#2<100 0\fi
  \ifnum#1>3 \ifnum#2<1000 0\fi
  \ifnum#1>4 \ifnum#2<10000 0\fi
  \ifnum#1>5 \ifnum#2<100000 0\fi
  \ifnum#1>6 \ifnum#2<1000000 0\fi
  \ifnum#1>7 \ifnum#2<10000000 0\fi
  \ifnum#1>8 \ifnum#2<100000000 0\fi
  \ifnum#1>9 \ifnum#2<1000000000 0\fi
  \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
  \expandafter\@firstofone\expandafter{\number#2}%
}

\makeatother

% image names are img000.png, img001.png, ..., img999.png
\setcounter{imgnr}{1}

\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{./images/img\padnum{3}{\value{imgnr}}.png
    \setcounter{imgnr}{2}

\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{./images/img\padnum{3}{\value{imgnr}}.png
    \setcounter{imgnr}{10}

\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{./images/img\padnum{3}{\value{imgnr}}.png
\end{document}
```

**Remarks:**

- No, an optional argument for `\padnum` via `\newcommand*{\padnum}[2][3]{...}` is *not* possible, because then `\padnum` is no longer expandable and the usage in the file names will break.

Comment: This solution looks good, but is lacking the possibility of specifying the number of padding zeros.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you! Just for me to learn: a macro with optional arguments is never expandable or just in this case?

Comment: @jrast The detection of the square bracket is based on `\futurelet`, which is an assignment and therefore not expandable.