# Remove leading zeroes from an integer

Tags: documentclass-writing, text-manipulation

In the documentclass I am writing, the user will input an integer such as `\lessonnumber` as an integer with possibly a number of leading zeroes, e.g. 4 as `04`. At some places in the document I will need the full form (`04`) and at others I only want to common form (`4`). How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How will the value of `\lessonnumber` be captured? Will it be entered as a string, e.g., via `\newcommand\lessonnumber{"04"}`? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico: As `\renewcommand{\lessonnumber}{04}`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I introduce `\stripzero`, which will work with the argument either in or not in braces.  The argument can be an expandable macro.

The macro works recursively.  The definition of `\stripzero` first expands its argument, which is needed to allow operation on macros such as `\lessonnumber`.  Once the argument is expanded, it calls on the recursion routine, which compares the next token to a `0`.  If it is not a zero, it prints the token and stops.  If the token is a `0`, it ignores/discards it, and calls itself again to look at the next token.

The trick to avoid the macro looking at the `\else` as its next argument is to `\expandafter` the macro, so as to absorb the `\else`.
If I have the recursion call upon `\stripzero` (rather than `\stripzerohelp`), the `\expandafter` is not necessary.  However, a two-macro recursion is also not most efficient, so I left the recursion routine calling directly upon itself, while retaining the `\expandafter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\stripzero#1{\expandafter\stripzerohelp#1}
\def\stripzerohelp#1{\ifx 0#1\expandafter\stripzerohelp\else#1\fi}
\begin{document}
\stripzero{4}

\stripzero 04

\stripzero 004

\stripzero{004}

\def\lessonnumber{00056}
\stripzero\lessonnumber

\stripzero{\lessonnumber}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Marc raises the interesting question of how to handle an argument of pure zeroes.  The above MWE strips them all away.  However, that may not be desired.  It may be desired to print out a single `0` if the argument is a string of zeros.

Therefore, I provide the following alternate implementation that checks the first non-zero token.  If it is a digit, it behaves as before.  But if the following token is not a digit, it concludes the number was a string of pure zeros and outputs a single `0`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\stripzero#1{\expandafter\stripzerohelp#1}
\def\stripzerohelp#1{\ifx 0#1\expandafter\stripzerohelp\else\checkrange{#1}#1\fi}
\def\checkrange#1{\ifx1#1\else\ifx2#1\else\ifx3#1\else\ifx4#1\else\ifx5#1\else%
  \ifx6#1\else\ifx7#1\else\ifx8#1\else\ifx9#1\else0\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi}
\begin{document}
\stripzero{4}

\stripzero 04

\stripzero 004

\stripzero{004}

\def\lessonnumber{00056}
\stripzero\lessonnumber

\stripzero{\lessonnumber}

\def\lessonnumber{000}
\stripzero{\lessonnumber}xyz
\stripzero\lessonnumber xyz
$\stripzero\lessonnumber\vec{x}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can see that `\stripzero` recursively parses the integer beginning with the first digit. Can you briefly explain how it does this?

Comment: @SimonKuang I have added some explanation.

Comment: Thank you! (I am learning TeX.) I still do not understand `\stripzerohelp` completely. How does `\stripzero\else` discard the first token?

Comment: @SimonKuang The very first token comes into `\stripzerohelp` as #1.  If it is a `0` token, nothing is done with it and the recursion is called again.  It is effectively discarded.  In my re-revision, I employ a `\expandafter` prior to `\stripzerohelp` to absorb the `\else`.

Comment: The macro `\stripzero` will fail if its argument is a sequence of zeros. (Then again such areguments may never occur.)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen It will not fail.  It will strip the zeroes and move on.  Try `\stripzero{000}xyz` or `\stripzero 000xyz` or even `$\stripzero 000\vec{x}$`.  It works just fine.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I get no error with `\def\lessonnumber{0}
\stripzero{\lessonnumber}xyz
\stripzero\lessonnumber xyz
$\stripzero\lessonnumber\vec{x}$`

Comment: @MarcvanDongen, that is most bizarre, given that there are no packages being used that could be outdated...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes (But this isn't really the main problem. The problem is that `\stripzerohelp` strips _all_ zeros if its argument consists of zeros only:-)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'm using LaTeX2e 2014/05/01,

Comment: @MarcvanDongen That is true, and likely not desired.  Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I have provided an alternate MWE to trap that case, if the OP wishes such behavior.

Comment: How can I make this work with an `xstring` command e.g. `\StrMid{2011-10-29--2-03}{15}{16}`?

Comment: @mf67 I'm sorry.  I am not proficient with `xstring`.

Answer (score 13):

## Numbers smaller than 2<sup>31</sup>-1

If the number fits in TeX's number range, then the number can be normalized with vanilla TeX's `\number`:

```
\number\lessonnumber\relax
```

The `\relax` at the end (or an empty curly brace pair) prevents that TeX looks for more digits after `\lessonnumber`. An expandable version must use a different trick:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\normalizedlessonnumber}{%
  \expandafter\@firstofone\expandafter{\number\lessonnumber}%
}
\makeatother
```

Then the closing curly brace serves as stopper for the TeX's digit scanner and the the curly braces will be gone as argument braces of `\@firstofone`.

The expandable e-TeX version with additional support for some arithmetic operations is:

```
\the\numexpr(\lessonnumber)\relax
```

## Unlimited integers

An expandable normalization for unlimited integer numbers an be done by `\bigintcalcNum` of package `bigintcalc`:

```
\bigintcalcNum{\lessonnumber}
```

## Adding leading zeros

If the number fits in TeX's integer range, then the following macro `\padnum` adds leading zeros (taken from my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250328/16967) to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/250326/16967)).

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\padnum}[2]{%
  \ifnum#1>1 \ifnum#2<10 0\fi
  \ifnum#1>2 \ifnum#2<100 0\fi
  \ifnum#1>3 \ifnum#2<1000 0\fi
  \ifnum#1>4 \ifnum#2<10000 0\fi
  \ifnum#1>5 \ifnum#2<100000 0\fi
  \ifnum#1>6 \ifnum#2<1000000 0\fi
  \ifnum#1>7 \ifnum#2<10000000 0\fi
  \ifnum#1>8 \ifnum#2<100000000 0\fi
  \ifnum#1>9 \ifnum#2<1000000000 0\fi
  \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
  \expandafter\@firstofone\expandafter{\number#2}%
}
\makeatother
```

`\padnum` is also expandable, that means, it can be safely used as part of file names, label names, ...

Usage. The first argument specifies the number of digits, which should be filled with leading zeros, when necessary. The second argument is the number to be formatted. Then `\padnum{3}{\lessonnumber}` with `\lessonnumber` as `04` will expand to `004`.

Comment: Hopefully the number of lessons won't be higher than `2^{31}-1` :-)

Comment: (I think) You are missing an `\expandafter`  before the brace in `\normalizedlessonnumber` definition.

Answer (score 8):

I would use the `\num` command from the [siunitx package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx). As explained in the manual the output of `\num` is highly configurable. To remove all of the zeros you could just type

```
\num[minimum-integer-digits=1]{\lessonnumber}
```

(If `\lessonnumber` is `0`  or `00` etc this will print `0`.) To print the "full form" of the number just use `\lessonnumber` or `\num[\lessonnumber]`. Conversely, if you wanted to pad `\lessonnumber` to a three digit number with leading zeros you can type

```
\num[minimum-integer-digits=3]{\lessonnumber}
```

For some more examples, you get the following output

[image]

from the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

  \num[minimum-integer-digits=1]{04} \num[minimum-integer-digits=3]{4}

  \num[minimum-integer-digits=1]{004} \num[minimum-integer-digits=4]{4}

  \num[minimum-integer-digits=1]{00004444} \num{00004}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for use of the `\num` macro. Unfortunately, your method won't automatically show the correct number of leading zeros if, say, the lesson number is "55" and the student has entered "055". Put differently, the method isn't fully automatic since the optional argument of `\num` needs to know the number of significant digits (without any leading zeros) in "lesson number".

Comment: @Mico Perhaps I misunderstand, but this seems to be OK. I have changed the MWE to use `054` and it produces what I expect. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear: I'm assuming it's not known in advance (a) how many significant digits `\lessonnumber` will contain and (b) how many leading zeros there may be. With your method, the correct value of the option `minimum-integer-digits` will depend on both of these unknowns.

Comment: @Mico My MWE shows that this is not a problem. You just print `\lessonnumber` if you want to print the input value and otherwise you use `\num[minimum-integer-digits=1]{\lessonumber}`. The latter will strip all leading zeros unless `\lessonnumber` is zero, in which case it prints `0`.

Comment: Thanks. I realize now I was confused. You may want to simplify your MWE to highlight the direct use of `\lessonnumber` for the full form vs. `\num[minimum-integer-digits=1]{\lessonumber}` for the stripped form.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

% Define "\strippednumber"
\newcommand\strippednumber[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(#1)}}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\lessonnumber{0004}  % we assume that the students won't enter arbitrary junk...

The value of \verb+\lessonnumber+, as entered by the student, is \lessonnumber.

The value of \verb+\lessonnumber+ without the leading zeros is \strippednumber{\lessonnumber}.
\end{document}
```

Aside: Under the method proposed here, numbers with more than fourteen [14!] significant digits will be rendered automatically in "scientific" notation. I trust this condition isn't particularly restrictive for the use case you've laid out. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Just use the fact that TeX strips off leading zeros when requested for a `<number>`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\printnumber}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    { \int_to_arabic:n { #2 } }
    { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\lessonnumber}{04}

\begin{document}

Full number: \printnumber\lessonnumber

Strip zero: \printnumber*\lessonnumber

\end{document}
```

Actually, without `*`, the macro `\printnumber` does nothing; but we can use the `*` to selectively strip off the zero when we wish to.

[image]

**Limitation:** only numbers up to 2<sup>31</sup>–1 are possible.

Answer (score 1):

This can be simply achieved with \number.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\lessonnumber{\@ifstar{\@lessonnumber}{\@lessonnumber@stripzero}}
\def\@lessonnumber#1{#1}
\def\@lessonnumber@stripzero#1{\number#1}
\makeatother

\lessonnumber{4}

\lessonnumber{04}

\lessonnumber*{004} 

\end{document}
```

The output will be:

[image]

Comment: This is already covered in [Heiko's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250816/5764).

Answer (score 0):

A simple but flexible solution is a counter and the `fmtcount` package:

> [image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\padzeroes[2]\newcounter{lesson}
\def\Lesson{{\addtocounter{lesson}{1}\padzeroes[2]%
\vskip1em\large\bfseries Lesson~\decimal{lesson}}\par\vskip.5em}
\begin{document}
\Lesson Some text of the lesson \arabic{lesson} 
\Lesson Some text of the lesson \padzeroes[7]\decimal{lesson}  \decimalnum{24}
\Lesson Some text of the lesson \padzeroes[3]\decimal{lesson}, not the \decimalnum{4}
\Lesson Some text of the lesson \padzeroes[1]\decimal{lesson}\par 
$\vdots$\addtocounter{lesson}{4}
\Lesson Some text of the lesson \decimal{lesson}
\Lesson Some text of the lesson \decimal{lesson}
\Lesson Some text of the lesson \ordinalstring{lesson} 
\Lesson Some text of the lesson \ordinal{lesson} 
\Lesson Some text of the lesson \Roman{lesson} 
\end{document}
```