# Reformat a string and remove leading zeros from substrings

Tags: strings

I have strings such as

```
2011-10-29--2-03
```

but I want to display them as

```
2011-10-29, p. 2, fig. 3
```

I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\def\ConvertID#1{%
\StrMid{#1}{1}{10}, 
p.~\StrMid{#1}{13}{13}, 
fig.~\StrMid{#1}{15}{16}
}

See \ConvertID{2011-10-29--2-03}.

\end{document}
```

and then tried various methods (from ideas at [Remove leading zeroes from an integer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250804/remove-leading-zeroes-from-an-integer)) to handle the last 2 characters, e.g.

```
\num[minimum-integer-digits=1]{\StrMid{#1}{15}{16}}
```

from `siunitx`, but it did not work.

How can this be done?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the last part will contain a number?

Comment: Maybe a format like `2011-10-29:2-03` should be better to use.

Comment: @egreg: Sorry for being late. Yes, the last 2 positions are 01, 02, ..., 2-digit numbers only.

Comment: @projetmbc: I had to use the ID as the file name too, and on PC this is not accepted by the OS, so I thought I'd use ‘--’. ‘_’ could have been an option too, but ‘here I am’ with a ‘legacy decision’…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\foo#1{\xfoo#1\relax}
\def\xfoo#1--#2-#3\relax{#1, p.\ \number#2, fig.\ \number#3\relax}
\begin{document}

\foo{2011-10-29--2-03}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please comment on the need to `\relax`?

Comment: @lhf it stops the `\number`  otherwise `\\foo{2011-10-29--2-03}4` would do `\number034` so produce 34 which is probably OK in this use but bad style to let primitive tex number parsing leak out like that,

Answer (score 5):

The following code is similar to [David's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/705984/4427), but it doesn't assume that page or figure numbers only consist of digits. For this to work we need to eat up leading zeros.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ConvertID}{m}
 {
  \mflxvii_convert:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \mflxvii_convert:n
 {
  \__mflxvii_convert:w #1 \q_stop
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__mflxvii_convert:w #1--#2-#3 \q_stop
 {% #1 is a date in ISO format, #2 is a page number, #3 is a figure number
  #1,~
  p.\ \__mflxvii_convert_eat:N #2 \q_nil ,~
  f.\ \__mflxvii_convert_eat:N #3 \q_nil
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__mflxvii_convert_eat:N
 {
  \quark_if_nil:NF #1
   {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { 0 }
     {% a zero, restart
      \__mflxvii_convert_eat:N
     }
     {% not a zero, finish up
      #1 \__mflxvii_convert_deliver:w
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__mflxvii_convert_deliver:w #1 \q_nil { #1 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ConvertID{2011-10-29--22-03}

\ConvertID{2011-10-29--022-3}

\ConvertID{2011-10-29--22-a2}

\edef\test{\ConvertID{2011-10-29--22-a2}}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If expandability is not of a concern, here's a variant of [matexmatics' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/705985/4427)

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ConvertID}{m}
 {
  \mflxvii_convert:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__mflxvii_convert_seq
\tl_new:N \l__mflxvii_convert_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mflxvii_convert:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__mflxvii_convert_seq { - } { #1 }
  \seq_item:Nn \l__mflxvii_convert_seq { 1 } -
  \seq_item:Nn \l__mflxvii_convert_seq { 2 } -
  \seq_item:Nn \l__mflxvii_convert_seq { 3 } ,~
  p.\nobreakspace \__mflxvii_convert_eat:e { \seq_item:Nn \l__mflxvii_convert_seq { 5 } },~
  f.\nobreakspace \__mflxvii_convert_eat:e { \seq_item:Nn \l__mflxvii_convert_seq { 6 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mflxvii_convert_eat:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__mflxvii_convert_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A 0* } { } \l__mflxvii_convert_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__mflxvii_convert_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mflxvii_convert_eat:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ConvertID{2011-10-29--22-03}

\ConvertID{2011-10-29--022-3}

\ConvertID{2011-10-29--22-a2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: note if my answer needed to be ammended to not assume digits I would just change `\number#3` to  `\number0#3`

Comment: How - with your first variant - to handle the unlikely and edge case of p. and/or f. being 0?  ;-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez One can add a layer checking whether the item is just `0` before calling `\__mflxvii_convert_eat:N`

Answer (score 4):

The answer below uses `\seq_set_split:Nnn` to split the argument of `\FormatDatePageFig`. It applies `\int_to_arabic:n` to the last item of this sequence.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__mf_format_seq
\NewDocumentCommand { \FormatDatePageFig } { m }
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__mf_format_seq { - } {#1}
    \seq_item:Nn \l__mf_format_seq { 1 } -
    \seq_item:Nn \l__mf_format_seq { 2 } -
    \seq_item:Nn \l__mf_format_seq { 3 } , ~ p. ~
    \seq_item:Nn \l__mf_format_seq { 5 } , ~ fig. ~
    \int_to_arabic:n { \seq_item:Nn \l__mf_format_seq { 6 } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\FormatDatePageFig{2011-10-29--2-03}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\setsepchar{-}
\newcommand\convertID[1]{%
  \readlist*\theID{#1}%
  \theID[1]-\theID[2]-\theID[3], p.\ \theID[5], fig.\ \number\theID[6]%
}
\begin{document}
\convertID{2011-10-29--2-3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The last part can be simplified with `\number\theID[6]`, as in the answer from David Carlisle. Then it is unnecessary to define `\trimzero`.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution employs LuaLaTeX and works with any utf8-encoded string, not just ASCII-encoded strings. It doesn't assume that the page or figure numbers consist of exactly 1 or 2 digits, respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
  function Convert ( s )
    s1=unicode.utf8.sub( s , 1 , 10 )
    
    s2=unicode.utf8.match ( unicode.utf8.sub(s,13) , "^.-%-" )
    s2=tonumber(unicode.utf8.sub(s2,1,-2))
    
    s3=unicode.utf8.match( s , "-%d*$" )
    s3=tonumber(unicode.utf8.sub ( s3, 2 ))
    
    return ( s1 .. ", p.\\ " .. s2 .. ", fig.\\ " .. s3)
  end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\Convert[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(Convert("#1"))}}

\begin{document}
\Convert{2011-10-29--2-03}

\Convert{2023-12-30--0123-01234}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't work if the page number is greater than 9. Neither does the OP's attempt, but…

Comment: @egreg For example `\Convert{2011-10-29--2-10}` and `\Convert{2011-10-29--2-023}` work.

Comment: @matexmatics But `2011-10-29-10-10` doesn't

Comment: page number always one digit seems unlikely, but also it isn't clear what you mean by your comment about utf-8 v ascii, since the conversion only works for input that is a sequence of `-` or digits, there is no difference between the two encodings, is there?

Comment: @egreg and DavidCarlisle: I've updated the code to incorporate your points.