Generate sequential padded barcodes with qrcode
How can I create a padded sequence of qrcodes with the qrcode package?
The following code throws an error:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qrcode} 
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\newcounter{asn}
\setcounter{asn}{1}
  
\begin{document}

%OK
\qrcode[height=1cm]{\theasn}

%Not ok
\qrcode[height=1cm]{\padzeroes[5]{\decimal{asn}}}

\end{document}

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \qr@texttoencode.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.12 ...[height=1cm]{\padzeroes[5]{\decimal{asn}}}


you need an expandable padding command, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250328/2388
